# When double mouse click enables Ins

Tags: rider

Just installed `JetBrains Rider`. When i opened `IDE` I've realased that when i double click mouse `INS`  enables (this `INS` on keyboard). This leds to crazy things inside IDE. I click INS on keybboard to disable this behaviour but next time when I double mouse click in `Rider` enables it again.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to VIM extension if someone face that